# jQuery sticky header jumps at specific height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a basic sticky header.
The header contains 2 parts: `top` and `main`. When page is scrolled down, i want to keep only the `.main` sticky (so that the `.top` becomes invisible).

I'm trying following code, but it is jerky and if the content has a specific height, it does not let scroll, starts jumping. I have captured video to illustrate the problem. Please see:
http://www.screenr.com/Z89H

Here's the demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/M33g4/

(you might not see the issue because of different screen height, in that case drag the results window to set its height about 535px).

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</header>
<section>

</section>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = $('header').outerHeight();

    if($(this).scrollTop() > height){
        $('header').addClass('sticky');    
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you will have fixed this by now but after encountering the same issue I came up with a solution:

The issue was caused by the document size not having enough leeway beneath the fold to fit the height of the overall header. This meant that if a visitor tried to scroll down, the sticky part of the header will become fixed, but immediately unfix itself.I believe it may be the bounce-back effect that causes the problem but I haven't tested to verify this.

In short, I fixed it by adding simple check to ensure that there is more than enough space beneath the fold by comparing the height of the body and the height of the window. i.e body height minus window height must be greater than the total header height. Here's the code that worked in my instance:

```
  // Sticky sub navbar
  var sub_nav_height = $('#sub-nav').outerHeight();
  var total_height = $('#main-head').outerHeight();
  var header_height = total_height - sub_nav_height;
  var content_height;
  var y;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Only make sticky if window is large enough not to cause jumping issue
    content_height = $('body').height() - $(window).height();
    if(content_height > total_height) {
      y = $(this).scrollTop();

      if($(this).scrollTop() > header_height) {
        $('#sub-nav').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
        $('#sub-nav').removeClass('fixed');
      }
    }
  });
```

There are two caveats which I decided were absolutely fine for my scenario. The first is that an extra calculation has been added every time the scroll event is triggered, but this hasn't caused me any performance issues. The second is that the sticky header functionality is simply disabled when a vistor's window is a problematic size, but again I had no qualms with this as the navbar could still just about be seen.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/M33g4/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = $('.top').outerHeight();

    if($(this).scrollTop() > height){
        $('header').addClass('sticky');    
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    }       
});
```

guess you got the wrong height.

**Updated:**

The blinking issue is caused by height changing (due to `position: fixed`)

check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/M33g4/6/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = $('.top').outerHeight();

    if($(this).scrollTop() > height){
        if($('.main.sticky').length == 0) {
            $('header').append(
                $('.main').clone().addClass('sticky'));
        }
    }else{
        $('.main.sticky').remove();
    }
});
```

and stick `.main` only:

```
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it has exactly same problem. Open your demo, resize the results window to make its height about 612px and see.

Comment: Updated. by cloning `.main` to avoid total height changing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/M33g4/3/

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = $('.top').height();

    if($(this).scrollTop() > height){
        $('.top').hide();    
        $('header').addClass('sticky');    
    }else{
        $('.top').show();
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');

    }

});
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
}

.top{
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

.main{
    height: 70px;
    background: green;
}

section{
    height: 560px;
    background: yellow;
}

.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target to the `top` but not to whole `header` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M33g4/4/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = $('header .top').outerHeight();

    if($(this).scrollTop() > height){
        $('header').addClass('sticky');    
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution has exactly same problem. Resize the 'results' window in your demo to about 585px and try to scroll, you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Set the height variable to 30:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = 30;

    if($(this).scrollTop() >= height){
        $('header').addClass('sticky');    
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    }

});
```

and change the css for the sticky class to the following:

```
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: -30px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Top is -30 instead of -40. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check how the content in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M33g4/29/) snaps to the top, under the header, but not visible. You might want to resize the Results window to about 500px. Is there a solution to this please?

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
   var height = $('.top').outerHeight();
    if($(this).scrollTop() > height){
        $('header').addClass('sticky');    
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    }

});
```